# Maven archetype generation

Tags: java, maven, portlet

I use **mvn archetype:create-from-project** command and I do not know how to customize my archetype, for example I have next prop xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>MyPortletName</portlet-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/context/portlet-context.xml</value>
        </init-param>

        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>My portlet</title>
        </portlet-info>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

And I want pass portlet name and title as parameters when generate archetype, and some lines in xml will be changed to this, for example:

```
...
<portlet-name>${portletName}</portlet-name>
....
<portlet-info>
        <title>${portletTitle}</title>
</portlet-info>
```

So I want a full customized template, it is possible?